Problemas de Visualización de PDFs en mi página Web - Error en iframe - embed
He desarrollo una pequeña aplicación web, la cual mediante un formulario en php recoge un listado de cantos para la Eucaristia dominical, los datos se cargan en una base de datos.
Tengo un archivo aparte en php el cual se conecta con la base de datos y hace las respectivas consultas y las almacena en variables.
Ejemplo
En la variable "$PadreNvar" se almacena el nombre del canto que fue seleccionado por ejemplo toma el valor de "Padre Nuestro Kairoi", ahora en el servidor tengo un archivo en pdf con el mismo nombre, es decir, Padre Nuestro Kairoi.pdf, lo que estaba haciendo era mostrarlo en la página mediante las etiquetas de html "embed" o "iframe" en la definición del src del html, para explicarme mejor:
Opción 1
<embed style="width:100vw; height: 100%;" src="../assets/Cantos/<?php echo $PadreNvar; ?>.pdf" type="application/pdf"></embed>

Opción 2
<iframe style="width:100vw; height: 100%;" src="../assets/Cantos/<?php echo $PadreNvar; ?>.pdf" type="application/pdf"></iframe>

El verdadero inconveniente lo tengo es que cuando lo comparto para visualización algunas personas lo pueden ver y otras no,
De hecho cree dos páginas una para ios y otra para android pues evidencié problemas en los visualizadores de pdf incorporados de cada dispositivos, pero aún así es intermitente.
Así tengo el código

Así les sale a algunos usuarios que presentan el error


Les envío los enlaces por si alguno desea consultar y hacer pruebas:
usando la etiqueta embed:
https://encuentrominmusica.online/embed.php
usando la etiqueta iframe
https://encuentrominmusica.online/iframe.php

Para empezar puedes probar estandarizando las URL y nombres de archivo cambiándolos a ASCII puro, sin tildes, eñe, sin comas o punto y coma, y sin espacios. Por ejemplo: Señor, Señor, Ten Piedad (Contestación).pdf quedaría: Senor_Senor_Ten_Piedad_(Contestacion).pdf. Si no fuera posible cambiar esto, tendrías que codificar esos caracteres. Mira esta pregunta y sus respuestas.

Y porque no lo haces con JS o PHP puro?? En mi caso lo veo mucho mejor, más fácil y rápido.
Para el HTML necesitas esto
<a href="#" id="linkView">Ver Nombre del Archivo</a>
<div class="showPDF"></div>

Y en JS
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#linkView').click(function(){
        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        iframe.width = '100%';
        iframe.height = '700px';
        iframe.src = 'file.pdf'; //Aqui iría el src (nombre) de tu archivo .PDF
        $('.showPDF').append(iframe);
    });
 });

También está la variante sin necesidad de hacer click en el Ver Nombre del Archivo, lo que te permite ver directamente el PDF sin problema
$(document).ready(function(){
    // $('#linkView').click(function(){
        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        iframe.width = '100%';
        iframe.height = '700px';
        iframe.src = 'file.pdf'; //Aqui iría el src (nombre) de tu archivo .PDF
        $('.showPDF').append(iframe);
    // });
 });

Este es el resultado con JS

Y por ultimo, puedes hacer una URL y mostrarlo con PHP puro
<?php
    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=Donwload_Name.pdf");
    readfile("file.pdf"); // Acá mandas el nombre de tu archivo

Con PHP el resultado es el mismo, solo que en Full Page.
PD1: Yo pienso igual que @aeportugal, debes nombrar de manera diferente esos archivos.
PD2: Intente ver tu web pero se tarda demasiado y me desesperé y preferí responderte. Espero te sirva esto 
